# consecutivo en una funcion php

Tags: php, mysql-workbench, phalcon

Hola tengo un problema que me urge mucho resolver espero me puedan ayudar.

tengo 2 tablas relacionadas las en una llamada def_cliente se agregan clientes y tienen un campo llamado no_cartera que indica un rango del cliente

en la otra tabla llamada def_consecutivo tengo los campos de:

- rango
- desde
- hasta
- contador

el rango del cliente hace que se asigne en esta tabla y por la cual el contador debe de indicar cuantos clientes hay en ese rango

tengo una función que ya que da cual es el numero que tengo en el contador

```
public function getConsecutiveByRange($rango)
{
   $sql ="SELECT contador FROM def_consecutivo WHERE rango_numeros=:rango";
   return $this->getResponseQueryOne($sql,["rango"=>$rango]);
}
```

Ahora necesito hacer la función que me ayude a aumentar el contador cuando se agregue un cliente.

quedo a expectativa de sus opiniones
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

y si...

```
function addClient($contador,$rango)
{
 $contador += 1;
 $sql = "update def_consecutivo set contador = $contador where rango_numeros = $rango"
 // ejecutas tu query y haces tu return de lo que desees
}
```

y para decremento

```
function remClient($contador,$rango)
{
 $contador -= 1;
 $sql = "update def_consecutivo set contador = $contador where rango_numeros = $rango"
 // ejecutas tu query y haces tu return de lo que desees
}
```

saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Pero ¿Cómo le digo que cuando el cliente este dentro de uno de los rangos aumente el contador para ese rango?

Comment: por ejemplo para el rango 01 que va desde 000000001 hasta 0000999999 cuando se agregue un cliente con no_cartera entre ese rango se aumente el contador de ese rango

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo de como son tus tablas de la bd? esto me ayudari para sugerirte mejor una posible respuesta. saludos.

Comment: claro; la primer tabla se llama def_cliente en esta tabla se agregan los clientes nombre apellido etc. el campo que me interesa de esa tabla es el de no_cartera que me indica un numero el cual se refiere a un rango. La segunda tabla se llama def_consecutivo que tiene campos de_ rango, desde, hasta, contador en esta tabla se establece el rango por ejemplo 01 desde que es el inicio del rango por ejemplo 000000001 y hasta que es el fin del rango por ejemplo 000999999 y contador que se refiere a el contador del numero de clientes que existen en ese rango el cual debe aumentar al agregar un cliente